# Bloquear el acceso al panel de administración de mi pagina web PHP

Tags: php, mysql

Buenas logre crear un sistema de cuentas usando $_SESSION con php y mysql, con registro y login pero cualquier persona sin necesidad de ingresar o registrarse puede acceder a mi panel de administración solo con el link por ejemplo: localhost/admin/posts.php y tiene el acceso total, lo que quiero hacer es que al intentar entrar en ese link no le permita y le bloquee el acceso, que debas poseer una cuenta registrada en la base de datos para poder acceder.

Archivo: login.php

```
<?php include("../app/controllers/users.php")?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">

  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />

  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="../style.css">

  <title>Login</title>
</head>

<body>

<?php include('../app/includes/header.php') ?>

  <div class="auth-content">
    <form action="login.php" method="post">
      <h3 class="form-title">Login</h3>
      <!-- <div class="msg error">
        <li>Username required</li>
      </div> -->
        
    <?php include('../app/helpers/formErrors.php'); ?>
        
      <div>
        <label>Username</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="<?php echo $username; ?>" class="text-input">
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Password</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" value="<?php echo $password; ?>" class="text-input">
      </div>
      <div>
        <button type="submit" name="login-btn" class="btn">Login</button>
      </div>
      <p class="auth-nav">Or <a href="register.php">Sign Up</a></p>
    </form>
  </div>

  <!-- JQuery -->
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script src="scripts.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Archivo: users.php

```
<?php

include("../app/database/db.php");
include("../app/helpers/validateUser.php");

$errors = array();
$username = '';
$email = '';
$password = '';
$passwordConf = '';
$table = 'users';

function loginUser($user){
    
    $_SESSION['id'] = $user['id'];
    $_SESSION['username'] = $user['username'];
    $_SESSION['admin'] = $user['admin'];
    $_SESSION['message'] = 'Ya posees 1 sesión abierta.';
    $_SESSION['type'] = 'success';
    header('location: index.php');
    exit();
}

if (isset($_POST['register-btn'])) {
  $errors = validateUser($_POST); 
    
    if (count($errors) === 0){
            unset($_POST['register-btn'], $_POST['passwordConf']);
            $_POST['admin'] = 0;
        
            $_POST['password'] = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        
            $user_id = create($table, $_POST);
            $user = selectOne($table, ['id' => $user_id]); 
        
            loginUser($user);

            
    } else {
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $passwordConf = $_POST['passwordConf'];
    }
       
}

    if (isset($_POST['login-btn'])) {
        $errors = validateLogin($_POST);
        
        if(count($errors) === 0){
            $user = selectOne($table, ['username' => $_POST['username']]); 
            
            if ($user && password_verify($_POST['password'], $user['password'])) {
            loginUser($user);
                } else {
                array_push($errors, 'Datos incorrectos, verifique su usario y contraseña.');
                } 
            }
        
        $username = $_POST['username'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
}

    
?>
```

Base de datos:

[image: imagen]

Comment: ¿Qué valores puede tener la columna _admin_?, ¿sirven para identificar el rol de usuario?

Comment: @Triby Sí, la columna admin es para indentificar el rol del usuario con los valores 0 y 1

Answer (score 0):

Lo recomendable sería que crearas una tupla en la tabla **usuarios** con el nombre **rol**, para un mejor mantenimiento y pensando en una expansión a futuro **te recomiento que crees una tabla rol y vincules el id del rol a la tabla de usuarios** de tal manera que no tengas limitaciones a futuro a la hora de crear un nuevo rol.

Ahora bien, con el tema de restringir a los usuarios del sistema si no tienen cuenta en el sistema, debes crear un `if` statement para cada ventana en la cual se quiere restringir el acceso en caso de que una sesion no se encuentre activa. Para esto sería ideal que utilizaras las variables de sesion de PHP `$_SESSION` así como también `sesion_start()`.

Luego de que profundices más sobre el tema, simplemente quedaría que en cada página que desarrolles, coloques algo como esto.

```
<?php 

include("../app/controllers/users.php");

// Agregamos los roles permitidos en esta página.
$roles_permitidos = array('ADMINISTRADOR', 'EDITOR', 'MODERADOR');

// Si el usuario actual conectado no se encuentra dentro del array de roles permitidos, lanzar error.
if(!in_array($_SESSION['USUARIO']['ROL'], $roles_permitidos)){

    // Puedes incluir una página personalizada para mostrar un error.
    include_once '../error.php';
    include_once '../footer.php';
    exit();
    
}

// De lo contrario, si coinciden los roles, ejecuta la vista que desees.

?>
```